# Is it possible for me to get null values I correlated sub queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got that syntax error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 47
>   Incorrect syntax near '('

after running this code:

```
select * 
from enrollment 
where grade = (select null(grade) from enrollment)
```

I was trying to run a correlated subquery to output null values of grade in an enrollment table.

Comment: To make things clearer, show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve].)

Comment: there is no function like `null(x)` in tsql

Comment: I am trying to output null values using correlated subqueries, I think my query pattern is wrong but please is there a way I could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was trying to run a correlated subquery to output null values of grade in an enrollment table.

I don't see how the question relates to a subquery, but I am wondering whether you just want:

```
select * from enrollment where grade is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The key issue with the question is that `null` is not a value.

That's why you can't type `a = null` or `a in (null)`.

You need to use `a is null` or `a is not null` to check if there is or there isn't a value.